# Collect conditional items while streaming in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, collections, java-stream

In Kotlin code, I have a list of objects and while processing it via `filter` and `map` I want to collect items of particular interest. And discard others.

For example, I am using `foreach` loop as below. Is it possible to make it better by using `map` instead of `foreach`?

```
fun main() {

    val exceptionRequests = mutableListOf<String>()

    listOf<String>("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
        .filter {
            it.length > 2
        }
        .forEach {
            try {
                if (it == "Name2") {
                    throw Exception(it)
                } // Throwing exception here like this for simplicity. In real case, business logic throws exception.
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                exceptionRequests.add(it)
            }
        }

    println(exceptionRequests) // This prints `Name2`.
}
```

Comment: that said, your current example is just an additional (complicated) filter - for `it == "Name2"` - perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: @Hulk In this example, for simplicity I have shown a simple ` it=="Name2`. Real code is a method which will do business logic and throw exceptions. So double filter is not possible.

Comment: @Hulk Unfortunately  mapmulti is not available in kotlin!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.mapNotNull`

```kotlin
val exceptionResults = listOf<String>("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
.filter {
    it.length > 2
}
.mapNotNull { name ->
    try {
        if (name == "Name2") {
            throw Exception(name)
        } 
        null
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        name
    }
}
println(exceptionRequests) // This prints `Name2`.
```

If exception isn't thrown, try catch expression will result in `null`.
If exception is thrown, try catch expression will result in `name`.
`mapNotNull` will filter out nulls (cases where exception wasn't thrown).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you compare it and throw an Exception and then add that in the catch block?

You can derive **exceptionRequests** as follow:

```
val exceptionRequests = listOf<String>("Name1", "Name2", "Name3")
.filter {
  it.length > 2 && it == "Name2"
}
```

Comment: In this example, for simplicity I have shown a simple ` it=="Name2`. Real code is a method which will do business logic and throw exceptions. So filter is not possible.